# Replacing an Arduino Uno with a 3.3V ATMega328p

Tags: atmega328p

For a school project my partner and I have been prototyping our system, a microcontroller + sensor + rf transceiver, with an Arduino Uno as the micro. The sensor and transceiver both run off of 3.3V, the Uno, 5V and cooperate using logic level shifters. We've recently designed our PCB's with the intention of using an ATMega328p in place of the Arduino Uno to save space. We also read on the spec sheet for the ATMega328P that it can operate from 1.8V - 5V so we designed the layout assuming we'd just run it at 3.3V and eliminate the need for level shifters.

However, we can't figure out [how to program the ATMega328p](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-42735-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega328-328p_datasheet.pdf) so that it works at 3.3V. We do have another Uno that we were hoping to use as a loader. From doing some online research, it seems like this can certainly be done, but our attempts have been unsuccessful so far and our deadline is approaching rather quickly. We were wondering if anyone had any experience with this sort of thing and could recommend a solution.

Here is the [data sheet of atmega328p](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-42735-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega328-328p_datasheet.pdf)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Arduino Uno IS an Atmega328p, there is no need to reprogram anything. You can easily supply it 3.3v as VCC and it will work fine

Comment: How to run at 3.3V - Supply it with 3.3V. That's it. The maximum speed is slightly lower, see figure 32-1 on page 369 of the datasheet. But you don't need to do any special configuration. The maximum voltage on any input pins is Vcc + 0.5 so the inputs can only go to 3.8V max.

Comment: 1 - You have to make sure the clock frequency you are running is supported by 3.3V. 2 - Make sure the brownout voltage is lower than 3.3V

Comment: As @WesleyLee correctly points out, at 3.3V the max. allowed clock frequency is about 13MHz. Make sure you provide an appropriate clock, or use the internal oscillator at 8MHz if you don't need maximum speed. - Thinking about it, make sure you program the fuses to the right values on the blank MCU. This includes type and speed range of the clock, BOD level &c.